# Changing options on an apex related list

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I'm using a VF page rendered as a pdf to print out a record of a custom object within salesforce

I'm using the `<apex:relatedList list=>` to print out a related list to the master object. What I wanted to do was customise the options that show on the pdf. Is there a way to do this with the  `<apex:relatedList list=>?` or is there a better way of printing out the related list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking to do here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_iteration_components.htm

This allowed me to print out a related list but define what columns i wanted to show on my pdf.

In this example, the account is the page controller and the Contact is the related list